# Group Similar in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I have option "Group similar" enabled, but Chrome developer tools does not group messages. Am I missing something? Or it works like this by design?

[image]

(I expect "zoom change" to be grouped)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because you have *Show timestamps* option enabled.

- Open Dev tools
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Search for "Timestamps" and select *Hide timestamps*

Reference: [Message stacking](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#message_stacking)

Answer (score 2):

It's because your console isn't grouping similar items.

- Open Developer Tools <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- Click the gear on the top right
- Ensure `Group Similar` is enabled
- Open the Panel <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Enter `Timestamps` and select the `Hide timestamps` option.